# Python: sort nested dictionaries with datetime as key

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, nested

I have a list of dictionaries (of dictionaries), each entry has a datetime object as the key.
How can I sort this in terms of keys?

```
from datetime import datetime

buffer = [{datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 42, 00): {'data': 46, 'id': 'john'}},
          {datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 54, 00): {'data': 48, 'id': 'george'}},
          {datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 36, 00): {'data': 49, 'id': 'paul'}},
          {datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 24, 00): {'data': 51, 'id': 'ringo'}}]
```

I'm after this:

```
[{datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 24, 00): {'data': 51, 'id': 'ringo'}},

{datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 36, 00): {'data': 49, 'id': 'paul'}},

{datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 42, 00): {'data': 46, 'id': 'john'}},

{datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 54, 00): {'data': 48, 'id': 'george'}}]
```

Comment: `sorted(buffer, key=lambda x: list(x))`.

Comment: You can sort in place: `buffer.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every dictionary has only one key:

```
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime

buffer = [{datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 42, 00): {'data': 46, 'id': 'john'}},
          {datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 54, 00): {'data': 48, 'id': 'george'}},
          {datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 36, 00): {'data': 49, 'id': 'paul'}},
          {datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 24, 00): {'data': 51, 'id': 'ringo'}}]

out = sorted(buffer, key=lambda k: list(k)[0])
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 24): {'data': 51, 'id': 'ringo'}},
 {datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 36): {'data': 49, 'id': 'paul'}},
 {datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 42): {'data': 46, 'id': 'john'}},
 {datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 3, 9, 54): {'data': 48, 'id': 'george'}}]
```

Comment: of course! Many thanks